# Is there bitcoin algorithms flowcharts or any other diagrams available?

Tags: c++

To make those who not familiar with C++ to understand the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Forum user and Armory client developer [etotheipi](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=31239) put together a few nice images covering some aspects of the Bitcoin protocol, mostly related to transaction construction and verification; see [this forum thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=29416).

Other than that, though, most of the documentation is in code only. If you're comfortable with another language, you could try looking at [BitcoinJ](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/), a Java implementation of Bitcoin (client node functionality only), [BitcoinSharp](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/), a C# port of BitcoinJ, [CBitcoin](http://cbitcoin.com/), a C99 Bitcoin library (also partial), [Bitcoin-Ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby), [BitcoinJS](http://bitcoinjs.org/), and/or [PyWallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet).

In the end, though, currently the only complete reference implementation of Bitcoin is the original C++ code, so biting the bullet might be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not speak directly to programmers.
The Khan academy has got a great set of conceptual videos about bitcoin internals

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/core-finance/money-and-banking/bitcoin/v/bitcoin-what-is-it